# Change size of web browser control in DocumentCompleted

Tags: c#, winforms

I am having a web browser control in a winform. In order to show the web content completely (without scroll bars), I need to get the size of the web content in DocumentComplete event. And then resize(refresh) the winform.

```
void wbControl_DocumentCompleted(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        wbControl.Height = wbControl.Document.Window.Size.Height;
        wbControl.Width = wbControl.Document.Window.Size.Width;
    }
```

But, Its not getting set from here. Old values remains the same.

Comment: Is the control using a dock of `Fill`? Then you need to resize the form, not the control.

Comment: I added an answer, your code did not work for me either but mine does.

Answer (score 3):

If `Document.Window.Size` does not do the trick, `Document.Body.ScrollRectangle` will usually work for you.

I added some width and height when resizing the form because of the borders of the form, when resizing only the control itself this is not something you have to do.

```
private void webBrowser_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    //If dockstyle = fill
    this.Width = webBrowser.Document.Body.ScrollRectangle.Width + 40;//Border
    this.Height = webBrowser.Document.Body.ScrollRectangle.Height + 40;//Border
    //If the control is not docked
    webBrowser.Size = webBrowser.Document.Body.ScrollRectangle.Size;
}
```